# How to run python script at my mac's terminal after being connected to GCP virtual machine?

Tags: python, ssh, terminal, google-cloud-platform

I followed the instructions from this answer (https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/27352/how-to-run-a-python-script-on-gcp-compute-engine) to connect to a virtual machine which I created on GCP Compute Engine and run a python script from the terminal of my laptop on GCP Compute Engine.

This answer suggests that after I have connected to the virtual machine then I must enter the following at the terminal of my laptop: `python your_script.py`

However, when I point to the exact location of my .py file and enter:

`python /Users/Paul/PycharmProjects/Eyeglasses_colour/Main.py`

the response is the following:

```
python: can't open file '/Users/Paul/PycharmProjects/Eyeglasses_colour/Main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

What is wrong? Can't I run my python script (while connected at the GCP virtual machine)?

Comment: You're in a completely different terminal. With no access to the local filesystem of your Mac... For example, `ls /Users` on the GCP machine should say that path doesn't exist

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, you are actually right. I am at my mac's terminal but I am connected to the vm's terminal so it is like being at the vm's terminal. Then how can I run my python script from my laptop on the GCP according to the instructions given by the answer above (see the link)?

Comment: That link is assuming your files are already on the remote server

Comment: Hm, yes, it seems so and it mostly makes sense in this way. However, my question at this post was exactly if I can run my python script located at my laptop without uploading any files on GCP or installing any python programs etc. In other words, if I can use only the computational resources of GCP (CPU, RAM etc) directly with the programs and folders existing at my laptop. So it seems that this is not possible?

Comment: That's not how code works, unfortunately. It must exist in GCP to run in GCP. You can mount an SSHFS to have it read your local filesystem as if it was its own, but the overhead of that would not be reliable

Comment: Ok, I got it. So essentially this link was answering the question 'How to run a python script on GCP from my laptop after I have uploaded it on GCP?'.

Comment: Yes, or just "how to run python on GCP". Doesn't matter where the code came from

Comment: Show I must upload my source code on GCP to run the python script. However it seems that I can run it with the python I installed on my laptop and it is not required to install python anew in the virtual machine. Am I right? (So I must upload my .py files on GCP but I can use the programs of my own laptop on it like the python I installed on my laptop??)

Comment: It's a completely different python installation. You should use virtualenv in both locations, and create the necessary requirements.txt file locally, copy it over then install it... https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files

Comment: Ok so, if I understand right, you mean that I must install anew python on GCP Compute Engine to even run my python script from my laptop even though it is already installed on my laptop?

Comment: Nothing on your laptop matters. I could SSH to that Google machine from my phone. My phone doesn't have python... And I can't run my phone apps on that server. Picture yourself walking into a Google data center without your laptop and opening a terminal on some machine. That's basically equivalent to what you're doing here. (for what it's worth, python is probably already installed)

Comment: I got it, you gave very clear answers @cricket_007! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not have access to any /Users folders on a Google Cloud machine because they're running Linux, and that's commonly a Mac path.

That link assumes your files are already on the server. There are several ways that can happen.

1. Code was initially written there
2. You checkout the code from version control.
3. You `scp` the files using [`gcloud compute scp`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/scp)

This problem does not apply to Python or Google's services. It's applicable to all remote SSH sessions